# Combining two images one over other using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, imagery

I have to combine images from different satellites (with different spatial and spectral resolution) such that features of both are present in the final image. I am using ArcGIS.

Please help me with your solution.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Also, please state what prior research you have conducted on the topic.